# Open source XQuery projects

Tags: open-source, xquery

Do you know about any open source projects written in XQuery? The larger the better. I want to improve my XQuery skills by reading existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xprocxq](http://code.google.com/p/xprocxq/) is/was an implementation of XProc in XQuery, and is the only significant XQuery  open source project I know of.

For a less conventional example of XQuery, I would recommend a look at the [XQSharp raytracer](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/samples/raytracer/index.htm) (caveat: I am a developer for XQSharp).

Comment: An updated link to the Raytracer code (spread across multiple files): https://github.com/qt4cg/qt4tests/tree/master/app/Demos

Answer (score 2):

1. GIT Hub

   1. Pomengrante ( XQuery deployment project )
   2. MarkLogic CQ ( Browser Based Xquery Query tool )
   3. XQuery-OAuth
2. Google code

   1. XQMVC -- simple MVC framework for XQuery
3. http://developer.marklogic.com/

   1. XQRunner
   2. XQDebug ( browser based step by step debugging )
   3. Semantic

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a self answer:

Google Search http://www.google.com/codesearch "for file:.xq$" gives about 1000 matches. Most of them small scripts.

Answer (score 1):

We host and/or link to a good number of XQuery open source projects at http://developer.marklogic.com/code.  There is plenty of code to read there for you.

Comment: Hey there Eric or kadalamittai, hopefully you get this message... I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448993/has-anyone-successfully-implemented-narthex-from-marklogic-com, and maybe you'd be able to comment?

Answer (score 1):

See the [XQuery Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery)  for a number of documented example XQuery applications