# Has anyone successfully implemented Narthex from marklogic.com?

Tags: xml, browser, editor, installation, marklogic

I'm liking what I read about [Narthex](http://code.google.com/p/narthex/), but the [bug list](http://code.google.com/p/narthex/issues/list) looks a touch scary, the reliance on a specific server install doesn't make me leap for joy, and the setup is a bit over my head.

What I'd ideally like to know is whether or not I should invest time in not just trying this project out but learning how to implement it.

My immediate and future needs require something like Narthex to aid in the creation of interfaces and collections of learning material, it would be in a controlled usage environment so a few bugs here and there doesn't faze me. If I can't save files like in Flash CS5, I'll hunt you down and install a copy of Flash CS5 on your computer, and make you use it Kathy Bates style.

If possible, I'd really appreciate some screenshots of Narthex in action, and I guess a look at MarkLogic server (I downloaded 4.2).

Thanks in advance,
d

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=phase rebuts your edit! But thanks for the catch :)

Comment: Would love to know where the -1 came from - this question is perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody? Darn, I've pretty much started creating an interface using YUI, XPath and a touch of PHP - I'll hit roadblocks I guess. Feel free to leave comments if you come across this question with any experiments with Narthex etc.

Answer (score 3):

Good to hear some interest around Narthex. I'm the original author of the project. The idea was to develop some web-based interfaces around a MarkLogic database that would allow you to perform basic CRUD operations. On top of that, I built a simple HTML front-end that allowed you to search, browse, and update individual documents. Next, I had hoped to build AtomPub and S3 front-ends as well.

I'd be very interested in other contributions or more requirements.

Please let me know if you have specific questions.